# Noisiness when playing sound using an AVAudioSourceNode

Tags: swift, avfoundation, watchos

I'm using [TinySoundFont](https://github.com/schellingb/TinySoundFont) to use SF2 files on watchOS. I want to play the raw audio generated by the framework in real time (which means calling `tsf_note_on` as soon as the corresponding button is pressed and calling `tsf_render_short` as soon as new data is needed). I'm using an AVAudioSourceNode to achieve that.

Despite the sound rendering fine when I render it into a file, it's really noisy when played using the AVAudioSourceNode. (Based on [the answer from Rob Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75032629/3151675), this might be because I ignore the timestamp property - I'm looking for a solution that addresses that concern.) What causes this issue and how can I fix it?

I'm looking for a solution that renders audio realtime and not precalculates it, since I want to handle looping sounds correctly as well.

[You can download a sample GitHub project here.](https://github.com/tamassengel/AVAudioSourceNode-test)

## ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var settings = Settings.shared

    init() {
        settings.prepare()
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button("Play Sound") {
            Settings.shared.playSound()

            if !settings.engine.isRunning {
                do {
                    try settings.engine.start()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Settings.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

class Settings: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = Settings()

    var engine: AVAudioEngine!
    var sourceNode: AVAudioSourceNode!

    var tinySoundFont: OpaquePointer!

    func prepare() {
        let soundFontPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GMGSx", ofType: "sf2")
        tinySoundFont = tsf_load_filename(soundFontPath)
        tsf_set_output(tinySoundFont, TSF_MONO, 44100, 0)

        setUpSound()
    }

    func setUpSound() {
        if let engine = engine,
           let sourceNode = sourceNode {
            engine.detach(sourceNode)
        }

        engine = .init()

        let mixerNode = engine.mainMixerNode

        let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(
            commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16,
            sampleRate: 44100,
            channels: 1,
            interleaved: false
        )

        guard let audioFormat = audioFormat else {
            return
        }

        sourceNode = AVAudioSourceNode(format: audioFormat) { silence, timeStamp, frameCount, audioBufferList in
            guard let data = self.getSound(length: Int(frameCount)) else {
                return 1
            }

            let ablPointer = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(audioBufferList)

            data.withUnsafeBytes { (intPointer: UnsafePointer<Int16>) in
                for index in 0 ..< Int(frameCount) {
                    let value = intPointer[index]

                    // Set the same value on all channels (due to the inputFormat, there's only one channel though).
                    for buffer in ablPointer {
                        let buf: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16> = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(buffer)
                        buf[index] = value
                    }
                }
            }

            return noErr
        }

        engine.attach(sourceNode)
        engine.connect(sourceNode, to: mixerNode, format: audioFormat)

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func playSound() {
        tsf_note_on(tinySoundFont, 0, 60, 1)
    }

    func getSound(length: Int) -> Data? {
        let array = [Int16]()
        var storage = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>.allocate(capacity: length)
        storage.initialize(from: array, count: length)

        tsf_render_short(tinySoundFont, storage, Int32(length), 0)
        let data = Data(bytes: storage, count: length)

        storage.deallocate()

        return data
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your edit. I would expect the pitch to be better, but the noise to be horrible. You're still constantly filling the buffer from timestamp 0, even though that's not the timestamp requested. I didn't realize that you're also using the wrong format (int 16, when you set the audio format to float 32). I would expect that to be horrible. You need the formats to match.

Comment: I've fixed the format mismatching, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The `AVAudioSourceNode` initializer takes a render block. In the mode you're using (live playback), this is a real-time callback, so you have a very tight deadline to fill the block with the requested data and return it so it can be played. You don't have a ton of time to do calculations. You definitely don't have time to access the filesystem.

In your block, you're re-computing an entire WAV every render cycle, then writing it to disk, then reading it from disk, then filling in the block that was requested. You ignore the timestamp requested, and always fill the buffer starting at sample zero. The mismatch is what's causing the buzzing. The fact that you're so slow about it is probably what's causing the pitch-drop.

Depending on the size of your files, the simplest way to implement this is to first decode everything into memory, and fill in the buffers for the timestamps and lengths requested. It looks like your C code already generates PCM data, so there's no need to convert it into a WAV file. It seems to already be in the right format.

Apple provides a good sample project for a [Signal Generator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/audio_engine/building_a_signal_generator) that you should use as a starting point. Download that and make sure it works as expected. Then work to swap in your SF2 code. You may also find the video on this helpful: [What’s New in AVAudioEngine](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc19/510/).

---

The easiest tool to use here is probably an AVAudioPlayerNode. Your SoundFontHelper is making things much more complicated, so I've removed it and just call TSF directly from Swift. To do this, create a file called `tsf.c` as follows:

```
#define TSF_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "tsf.h"
```

And add it to `BridgingHeader.h`:

```
#import "tsf.h"
```

Simplify ContentView to this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var settings = Settings.shared

    init() {
        // You'll want error handling here.
        try! settings.prepare()
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button("Play Sound") {
            settings.play()
        }
    }
}
```

And that leaves the new version of Settings, which is the meat of it:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

class Settings: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = Settings()

    var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    var tsf: OpaquePointer
    var outputFormat = AVAudioFormat()

    init() {
        let soundFontPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GMGSx", ofType: "sf2")
        tsf = tsf_load_filename(soundFontPath)

        engine.attach(playerNode)
        engine.connect(playerNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)

        updateOutputFormat()
    }

    // For simplicity, this object assumes the outputFormat does not change during its lifetime.
    // It's important to watch for route changes, and recreate this object if they occur. For details, see:
    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_route_changes
    func updateOutputFormat() {
        outputFormat = engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    }

    func prepare() throws {
        // Start the engine
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
        try engine.start()
        playerNode.play()

        updateOutputFormat()

        // Configure TSF. The only important thing here is the sample rate, which can be different on different hardware.
        // Core Audio has a defined format of "deinterleaved 32-bit floating point."
        tsf_set_output(tsf,
                       TSF_STEREO_UNWEAVED,            // mode
                       Int32(outputFormat.sampleRate), // sampleRate
                       0)                              // gain
    }

    func play() {
        tsf_note_on(tsf,
                    0,   // preset_index
                    60,  // key (middle C)
                    1.0) // velocity

        // These tones have a long falloff, so you want a lot of source data. This is 10s.
        let frameCount = 10 * Int(outputFormat.sampleRate)

        // Create a buffer for the samples
        let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(frameCount))!
        buffer.frameLength = buffer.frameCapacity

        // Render the samples. Do not mix. This buffer has been extended to
        // the needed size by the assignment to `frameLength` above. The call to
        // `assumingMemoryBound` is known to be correct because the format is Float32.
        let ptr = buffer.audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers.mData?.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
        tsf_render_float(tsf,
                         ptr,                // buffer
                         Int32(frameCount),  // samples
                         0)                  // mixing (do not mix)

        // All done. Play the buffer, interrupting whatever is currently playing
        playerNode.scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil, options: .interrupts)
    }
}
```

You can find the full version at [my fork](https://github.com/rnapier/AVAudioSourceNode-test). You can also see the first commit, which is another approach that maintains your SoundFontHelper and does conversions to deal with it, but it's much simpler to just render the audio correctly in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to convert the result based on the Apple project you linked, but the result is even noisier. I updated the question with details. Also, can you please suggest how should I pass the timestamp information to `tsf_render_short` or `tsf_render_float?`

Comment: I would expect you need to render everything into your own buffer, and then pull from that buffer.  "Depending on the size of your files, the simplest way to implement this is to first decode everything into memory, and fill in the buffers for the timestamps and lengths requested."  I don't know this library. You'd need to see if it it supports rendering a specific range of frames. But assuming it doesn't, you would render them all and serve them up as needed. The key is to make sure that the samples you write match what was requested (the correct range of samples in the correct format)

Comment: It looks like you're currently in a mode of trying to find example code and copying it, and gluing that together with other copied code. That doesn't work for real-time audio. You need to know what the code is doing, and what the system is asking for. You can't avoid that. The settings all mean something, so you can't just copy an example; you have to know what the setting means.

Comment: Am I correct that you want to build a little synthesizer with custom voices? This is probably going to be a lot easier to build on top of AVAudioPlayer as a starting point, just to get your head around it. You have a "create a WAV" function already. Try handing that to `AVAudioPlayer(data:)`, and get that working. It's a kind of clunky solution, but it's a good starting point to get you moving forward. The better tool would probably be AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer, but that's more complicated to setup (and the docs are confusing when you want to build really simple things).

Comment: I fixed the audio format mismatch and threw the file system code out, see the updated question. Unfortunately, I don't see how I can use the timestamp information to only fill the right parts of the buffer, can you please show me how that would work in this case? Also, the audio still has a lower pitch despite avoiding the usage of the file system.

Comment: Also, your guess is correct, I want to make a synth that handles the SF2 format. "Try handing that to AVAudioPlayer(data:), and get that working. It's a kind of clunky solution, but it's a good starting point to get you moving forward." - I would prefer a cleaner solution, but that can work as well (if it's not too noisy when being used this way)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250905/discussion-between-tamas-sengel-and-rob-napier).

Comment: I just checked and this solution doesn't work with looping sounds, since it prerenders the sound and not playing it live. This is not what I'll need.

Comment: Real-time audio rendering with looping (and I assume you also want multiple simultaneous voices if you're building a synthesizer) is too large for me on Stack Overflow. I would generally do that as a medium-sized project. Best of luck; I hope someone can help you further. I wish there were really helpful documentation I could point you to. It's taken me a very long time to learn how audio works, mostly by building things, and I still keep discovering new things about it.

Comment: To your fundamental question about AVAudioSourceNode, the answer is that the system will poll you for the samples it should play over various time intervals in the future. It's your job to compute and return the correct samples for that time interval. The interfaces for that are fairly complicated (along the lines of the `ptr` assignment in my answer) and I don't have a simple summary of how to do it correctly. Someone else might. Best of luck with it.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, hopefully, I'll be able to figure it out. Have a nice day!